# MySQL user-defined variables losing value immediately?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters

So I am having an issue with MySQL 5.5 that is about to drive me insane. I have a few nested stored procedures and one of them inserts some data into a table and then selects the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` into an out-bound parameter. The following is my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `createNewSession`(
    in inputIP varchar(15),
    in inputPostTime bigint,
    in inputPostInterval bigint,
    in inputPlatform varchar(45),
    out outSessionID int)
BEGIN
    insert into myDB.session (IP, StartTime, LastPost, Platform) 
        values (inputIP, inputPostTime - inputPostInterval, inputPostTime, inputPlatform);

    select LAST_INSERT_ID() into outSessionID;
END;$$
```

Now, if I pass the correct parameters (ie: parameters that I have tested against the insert statement and are properly working) and call the following I will get the correct ID back

```
CALL myDB.createNewSession('127.0.0.1', 1310062874228, 1310062894228, 'Platform', @outVar);
select LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

However if I call the following then I am returned a `BLOB` parameter with a `?` value.

```
CALL myDB.createNewSession('127.0.0.1', 1310062874228, 1310062894228, 'Platform', @outVar);
select @outVar;
```

Why would this be happening? This stored procedure has been working for a month+ at this point and as far as I know nothing has changed to the DB settings. Why would I be receiving anything other than `LAST_INSERT_ID()` upon selecting the outbound parameter from the stored procedure?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Going crazy over here...

**EDIT**

The error that I'm getting when calling the top-level stored procedure is as follows:

```
Error Code: 1264. Out of range value adjusted for column 'outSessionID' at row 68
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is the table structure

```
Field Type Null Key Extra
'SessionID', 'int(11)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'IP', 'varchar(15)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'StartTime', 'bigint(20)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'LastPost', 'bigint(20)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'Platform', 'varchar(45)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
```

**EDIT 3**

So after messing around some more I have found that the following queries when called together will also select a BLOB parameter with value of '?'

```
set @tempVar = 25;
select @tempVar;
```

Shouldn't this return 25?

Comment: are you using msql workbench?

Comment: Yes I am using MySQL workbench. The error occurs no matter where I hit the DB from though.

Comment: Ok, just out of curiosity, how does it look in the data viewer? (if you right click the field)

Comment: Yes the parameters are identical. This is to show that the problem is with assigning LAST_INSERT_ID() into the outbound parameter is not working. As far as how the data looks in the data viewer, the cell has a box in it that says "BLOB" and when I copy the field contents out and paste them I receive a "?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
SET outSessionID := LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

within the proc instead of doing the SELECT.

Comment: I'm already more or less doing this with the SELECT INTO statement, but I just tested this method and again I am receiving the BLOB parameter with the ? value instead of the INT value I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, I know, but using SET is the more straightforward way IMO; and maybe it would have helped :)
Well, though I don't think this will really help, but could you post your table definition? And did you try this with other (older) versions yet?

Comment: Yea this definitely looks like a more straight-forward way to go. I have not used older versions but this stored procedure was working fine 3 hours ago. Is there a way I can see a changelog of server settings or something along those lines? The replica of the DB that I have hosted locally still works fine. Also I posted the table definition above

Comment: What does this return:

SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDB' AND TABLE_NAME = 'session'

Comment: It returns 186. Calling LAST_INSERT_ID() will return the correct value, so I don't think it has to do with the AUTO_INCREMENT value. Additionally, if I select the outbound parameter within the stored procedure, then the correct value is returned so it is being assigned correctly. However, if I select the parameter that I pass in to the stored procedure after the SP call then it returns the blob value, so it must have something to do with a memory setting?

Comment: Added an additional edit. It seems that all user-defined variables that I utilize in this particular instance of MySQL immediately lose their values.

Comment: well, what did you change in those three hours before it stopped working

Comment: I have changed nothing, however I am not the only one with access to the DB. It also seems that EXTERNAL connections will have user-defined variables automatically cast into BLOB variables that have the correct value but in the wrong format where as INTERNAL connections will have the user-defined variables cast correctly.... wtffff